# Text extraction after dom traversal returns empty

Tags: html, list, xml, recursion

I would like to extract the text from each visited node but while traversing and build a list.
I only get an empty result.
Here is the following attempt using `dom.el`

```el
(defun extract-text-from-dom (dom-node)
  "Recursively extract text from a DOM-NODE."
  (cond
   ((null dom-node) "")
   ((dom-text dom-node) (dom-text dom-node))
   (t
    (mapconcat
     #'extract-text-from-dom
     (dom-children dom-node)
     " "))))

(let* ((html "<div><p>This is a <b>sample</b> text.</p> <br><h1>Another Text</h1></div>")
       (dom-tree (libxml-parse-html-region 1 (length html) html))
       (text (extract-text-from-dom dom-tree)))
  (message "Extracted Text: %s" text))
```

Comment: In addition to [db48x's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/79333/15748) on the correct usage of `libxml-parse-html-region`, the reason `extract-text-from-dom` returns an empty result is because of the `(dom-text dom-node)` check. This will return a non-`nil` empty string `""` for any parent nodes that do not contain text, thus ending the recursion early. Have you tried using `dom-texts` from `dom.el` instead?

Comment: ok, thanks, let me check on that

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I notice is that `libxml-parse-html-region` doesn’t take a string to parse. Instead it parses a region of the current buffer. Use `C-h f` to look up help for functions. It will tell you what arguments they take, and the docstring will describe those arguments in detail. Try this instead:

```lisp
(let ((html "<div><p>This is a <b>sample</b> text.</p> <br><h1>Another Text</h1></div>"))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert html)
    (let ((text (extract-text-from-dom (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max)))))
      (message "Extracted Text: %s" text))))
```

Note also that dom nodes can have both text *and* children, so your extraction function isn’t quite right.

Comment: I instead have this error: `*** Eval error ***  Wrong number of arguments: libxml-parse-html-region, 0
`

Comment: Maybe it depends on the Emacs version. What does `C-h f` say? Always use `C-h f`.

Comment: @db48x `libxml-parse-html-region` took 2 mandatory arguments up to and including Emacs 28.

Comment: @alexander Try replacing `(libxml-parse-html-region)` with `(libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))`.

Comment: @Basil, I have updated the question at: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79337/web-scrapping-traversal-using-dom-el
can you please have a look?

Comment: @alexander I have now posted some comments and suggestions on that.

Comment: thanks, I'm looking into it.