# Web scraping traversal using dom.el, pcase error: Unknown pattern

Tags: html, list, xml, recursion

I would like to traverse the dom tree, extract the text and build a list after visiting each node.

Implementing the recursion with the help of `text-tag` function returned an unknown pattern error.

The current attempt leads to an error of:
`Unknown push pattern: (push (dom-text node) text-list)`

I believed the test condition matched but I didn't know where it went wrong.

```el
(setq text-list '())

(defun text-tag (x)
  (let ((node (dom-node x)))
    (pcase (dom-tag node)
      ((and (pred stringp) str) str)
      ('comment '())
      ((push (dom-text node) text-list)
       (mapconcat #'text-tag (dom-children node)))
      )))

(defun apply-extraction (tag-entries)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert tag-entries)
    (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))))
      (text-tag (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body))))))

(let ((mytree "<html>
     <head>
         <title>Demo: Gradient Slide</title>
     </head>
     <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
     <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"dist/build.css\">
     <body>
         <header data-table=\"testtable\">
             <h1 data-field=\"testfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
             <h1 data-field=\"newfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
         </header>
         <div class=\"wrap\"> Sample Text <p class=\"format\" data-attribute=\"somethingsomething\">Welcome to this page</p>
             <div class=\"flex-grid generic-card\">
                 <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE -->
                 <div class=\"card loading\">Text </div>
                 <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE 
                   this multiline comment 
                   -->
                <div class=\"card loading\"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>"))
  (apply-extraction mytree))
```

This kept me wondering. If `pcase` is used to negate a test case?

Comment: You need our help to do what?  Please explain what the problem is, what error messages you get and what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @FranBurstall, I updated the question and the error I got.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but it might be you're missing `_` pattern in your `pcase`:

```
(defun text-tag (x)
  (let ((node (dom-node x)))
    (pcase (dom-tag node)
      ((and (pred stringp) str) str)
      ('comment '())
      (_
       (push (dom-text node) text-list)
       (mapconcat #'text-tag (dom-children node) "")))))
```

Assuming you would like to have a "catch-all" clause to extract and save text into `text-list` following by recursive call for all children.

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to traverse the dom tree, extract the text and build a list after visiting each node.

Have you tried using the functions `dom-strings` (returning a list) or `dom-texts` (returning a string) from the built-in library `dom.el`?

> I'm confused on implementing the recursive function `text-tag` to perform the said operation and I need your assistance.

It would be helpful if you described in more detail which text precisely you are interested in extracting.

> The current attempt leads to an error of:
> `Unknown push pattern: (push (dom-text node) text-list)`

Maxim Kim's [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/79339/15748) already correctly identifies this as arising from invalid use of `pcase`.

A call to `pcase` follows the pattern `(pcase EXP (PATTERN CODE...)...)`.

The call to `(push (dom-text node) text-list)` is in the place where a `PATTERN` was expected, but there is no built-in `pcase` pattern that starts with `push`, hence the error.

---

Some inline comments:

```el
(setq text-list '())
```

When defining your own variables and functions, it is best to name them with a unique prefix such as `my-`, to ensure that they don't clash with other Elisp code.  Also, when a variable is expected to be used by others (such as a function you define), it is best to define it with `defvar` instead of `setq`, for example:

```el
(defvar my-text-list ()
  "List of HTML strings.")
```

---

```el
(defun text-tag (x)
  (let ((node (dom-node x)))
```

When `text-tag` is first called in `apply-extraction`, it is passed a DOM node (specifically `body`).

So passing the `body` to `dom-node` is both unnecessary and potentially invalid.

---

```el
    (pcase (dom-tag node)
      ((and (pred stringp) str) str)
```

This `pcase` call is inspecting the `dom-tag` (which is meant to be a symbol) of `node`, but the pattern is looking for a string.

So the pattern should be matched against `node`, not `(dom-tag node)`.

---

```el
      ('comment '())
```

What about `script`?

---

```el
      ((push (dom-text node) text-list)
       (mapconcat #'text-tag (dom-children node)))
```

This simultaneously builds a list of strings, and also returns their concatenation.

Are both operations really needed, or can you get away with doing only one or the other?

Putting this all together, we would get something like:

```el
(pcase x
  ((pred stringp)
   (push x text-list)
   x)
  ((app dom-tag (or 'comment 'script))
   ())
  (_
   (mapconcat #'text-tag (dom-children x))))
```

---

```el
(defun apply-extraction (tag-entries)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert tag-entries)
    (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))))
      (text-tag (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body))))))
```

`dom-by-tag` returns a list of all children nodes whose tag is `body`, but most of the time all you need is the HTML's first `body` child.

For that, you can use `dom-child-by-tag` instead.

---

```el
 (let ((mytree "<html>
     <head>
         <title>Demo: Gradient Slide</title>
     </head>
     <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
     <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"dist/build.css\">
     <body>
         <header data-table=\"testtable\">
             <h1 data-field=\"testfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
             <h1 data-field=\"newfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
         </header>
         <div class=\"wrap\"> Sample Text <p class=\"format\" data-attribute=\"somethingsomething\">Welcome to this page</p>
             <div class=\"flex-grid generic-card\">
                 <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE -->
                 <div class=\"card loading\">Text </div>
                 <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE 
                   this multiline comment 
                   -->
                <div class=\"card loading\"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>"))
   (apply-extraction mytree))
```

Note that `libxml-parse-html-region` preserves in the returned DOM all blanks present in the original HTML. Is this desirable in your use-case?

---

To wrap up, here is how I would refactor this:

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(require 'dom)
(eval-when-compile
  ;; For `string-join' prior to Emacs 29.
  (require 'subr-x))

(defun my-dom-strings (node)
  "Return a flat list comprising all string nodes under HTML NODE.
Like `dom-strings', but also ignores HTML `comment' nodes."
  (cond ((stringp node)
         (list node))
        ((not (memq (dom-tag node) '(comment script)))
         (mapcan #'my-dom-strings (dom-children node)))))

(defun my-html-strings (html)
  "Collect string nodes under HTML's `body' in a list."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert html)
    (let ((dom (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))))
      (my-dom-strings (dom-child-by-tag dom 'body)))))

(setq html "\
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo: Gradient Slide</title>
    </head>
    <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"dist/build.css\">
    <body>
        <header data-table=\"testtable\">
            <h1 data-field=\"testfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
            <h1 data-field=\"newfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
        </header>
        <div class=\"wrap\"> Sample Text <p class=\"format\" data-attribute=\"somethingsomething\">Welcome to this page</p>
            <div class=\"flex-grid generic-card\">
                <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE -->
                <div class=\"card loading\">Text </div>
                <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE
                     this multiline comment
                  -->
                <div class=\"card loading\"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>")

(setq strings (my-html-strings html))
;; => ("..." "Skeleton Screen" ...)

(string-join strings)
;; => "... Skeleton Screen ..."
```